Inconsistent equations from two different references
Consider the following diagram.
Because any point in the same level must have the same hydrostatic pressure.
Using the red line as a reference, I have
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
(a+b)\rho_1 \bcancel{g}  &= 2b\rho_2\bcancel{g}\\
\end{align}
But using the blue line as a reference, I have
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
a \rho_1 \bcancel{g} &= b\rho_2 \bcancel{g}\\
\end{align}
Why are they different? I am really confused.


Why is the blue line relevant? If you remove the stuff above that line, the remaining stuff isn't in equilibrium.

Because any point in the same level  must have the same hydrostatic pressure.

“I have [equation]. But…I have [equation]” is not clear. What model and reasoning are you applying to get these equations? I’d expect something like a force balance, or Pascal’s law, or hydrostatic pressure variation. Clarification is also needed as to why you consider the equations to be inconsistent. Why can't two different equations both be true?

Thank you for editing the question to give the premise. Is the premise true? By subtracting twice the second equation from the first, we find that $a=b$, which means that the liquids have the same density. From this, we conclude that the premise doesn’t hold if the line doesn’t pass through regions of uniform density of a connected fluid. If liquids 1 and 2 have different densities, the red reference line is valid, but the blue one isn’t. Nor, for example, is a reference at the right surface level, which gives zero (gauge) pressure on the right but represents some of liquid 1 on the left.

@DG "any point in the same level must have the same hydrostatic pressure" - only if the liquid below that level is homogenous i.e. it has the same density at each depth. This is true of the red line, but it is not true of the blue line unless we assume that the two liquids have the same density.

@gandalf61: Thanks. Where is the constraint "only if the liquid below that level is homogenous" documented?

@DG I think it is fairly self evident. But you can formally derive it by starting at the bottom of the trough, where the pressure must be equal all the way along, and then working upwards from there applying the hydrostatic equilibrium equation $dP = -\rho g \space dh$


Because any point in the same level must have the same hydrostatic pressure.

Is the premise true?
By subtracting twice the second equation from the first, we find that a=b, which means that the diagram must not to be to scale and that the liquids must have the same density.
From this, we conclude that the premise doesn’t hold if the line doesn’t pass through connected regions of a uniform-density fluid.
In other words, if liquids 1 and 2 have different densities, the red reference line is valid, but the blue one isn’t.
This should also be evident by considering a horizontal reference at the level of the right surface, which corresponds to zero (gauge) pressure on the right but represents some of liquid 1’s weight on the left. These two values can’t be equal.

So how should the premise be corrected? According to @gandalf61: "only if the liquid below that level is homogenous". I need the proof of this constraint too.

The proof ultimately comes from the force balance that relates the vertical pressure differential acting on a small fluid element to the element’s downward weight. A single fluid is assumed, and so the derived relationship $\Delta P=\rho gh$ contains only a single density $\rho$. The blue reference line switches fluids.

Sorry. I don't understand. The sentences sound confusing. I cannot find the interconnection between each statement. They may be understandable only for experts. Simpler ones please.

To help gauge how best to edit the answer for clarity: Are you familiar with how $\Delta P=\rho gh$ is derived?

A cube of fluid with side length $L$ at a surface is subject to atmospheric pressure $P_0$ (downward top force $P_0L^2$) and its weight (downward force $\rho gL^3$). If the fluid is motionless, all vertical forces on the cube must balance, requiring a bottom upward force of $L^2(P_0+\rho gL)$ and thus a lower pressure of $P_0+\rho gL$. We can apply the same reasoning to a cube below that cube and anywhere else in the fluid to conclude that the pressure changes with vertical distance $h$ as $\Delta P=\rho gh$. Agreed?

I need to prove "The pressure is the same at all points on the same level within a connected fluid."

Start somewhere in the connection (single pressure at a point), move horizontally leftward through liquid 2 (constant pressure), and then move upward through liquid 2 in the left arm of your diagram to as far as the red reference line (pressure change $\Delta P=\rho_2gh$). Then do the same thing up the right arm, finding the same pressure change. Does this clarify the strategy?

Like this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/426774/202596?

Exactly. The problem with the blue reference line is that the conceptual path no longer moves through liquid 2 alone. However, you could use that path and the same relations to show that that pressure is higher there on the left side by $(\rho_2-\rho_1)gb$.
